# AssertionError crashes Mocha

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I'm running unit tests using Mocha, and instead of showing all the thrown AssertionErrors in the reporter Mocha crashes on the first error. Any suggestions?

The error I get at crash is this:

```
/Users/Robert/Code/JRJ/Server/node_modules/chai/lib/chai/assertion.js:106
      throw new AssertionError(msg, {
            ^
AssertionError: expected 200 to equal 202
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

It's the same no matter if I use Chai or the built-in assert library. I run Mocha with this command (I run it with `npm test`):

```
mocha --reporter 'spec' --recursive
```

And the library versions I'm using are these:

- node: 0.10.18
- mocha: 1.12.0
- chai: 1.8.0
- hapi: 1.10.0

The test code:

```
    var hapi = require('hapi'),
        expect = require('chai').expect,
        assert = require('assert');

    describe("Customer API", function(){
      var server = require('../../../../src/apis/customer');

      //works as expected 
      describe('simpleExample', function(){
        it("should cause a test failure", function(done){
            expect(200).to.equal(202);
            done();
        });
      });

      //crashes Mocha
      describe('Authentication', function(){
        it('Should get user token', function(done){
          server.inject("/auth?username=test@test.com&password=testa", function(res){
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(202); //returns 200, crashes Mocha (the expected 202 is intentional to cause an assertion error)
            //assert.ok(res.statusCode === 202);
            expect(res.payload).to.be.a('string');
            expect(res.payload).to.have.length(16);
            done();
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because it's the way Mocha works. Exceptions in asynchronous calls needs to be caught and passed to the done callback, this even includes AssertionErrors. There is an error in the Mocha documentation and I've opened a GitHub issue to resolve this (https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/982).